# Impossibility of embedding of $C_4$ in $l_2$ with distortion better than $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, computer-science

I am reading [Lecture notes on metric embeddings,Jirı Matousek](https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ematousek/ba-a4.pdf). I have a question regarding Proposition 3.4.1, the lower bound. In the following $C_4$ is the 4-cycle with vertext set $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$, equipped with the shortest path metric $d$.

It is stated in the lemma, due to the **short diagonals lemma** (sum of squares of diagonals is at most sum of squares of four sides), any non-contracting embedding would contract a diagonal by at least $\sqrt{2}$. What I have able to show is that one of the distinct pairwise distance should increase by $\sqrt{2}$, not just the diagonals.

Suppose, $f:C_4\rightarrow l_2^k$ is a non contarcting embedding, meaning $\Vert f(v_i) - f(v_j)\Vert_2 \geq d(v_i,v_j)$, forall $i\neq j$. Now suppose that $\Vert f(v_i) - f(v_j)\Vert_2 < \sqrt{2}d(v_i,v_j)$ forall $i\neq j$. We will use $f_{i,j}$ to denote $f(v_i)-f(v_j)$ and $d_{i,j}$ to denote $d(v_i,v_j)$.

Now $\Vert f_{1,3}\Vert_2^2 + \Vert f_{2,4}\Vert_2^2\geq d_{1,3}^2 + d_{2,4}^2 = 8$

And $\Vert f_{1,2}\Vert_2^2 + \Vert f_{2,3}\Vert_2^2 + \Vert f_{3,4}\Vert_2^2 +\Vert f_{4,1}\Vert_2^2 < 2(d_{1,2}^2+d_{2,3}^2+d_{3,4}^2+d_{4,1}^2) = 8$. This contradicts the **short diagonals lemma**. So there exists $i\neq j$ such that $\Vert f(v_i) - f(v_j)\Vert_2 \geq \sqrt{2}d(v_i,v_j)$.

But in the notes, it is stated that one of diagonals should have large distortion, not any pair of nodes. May be I am missing something.

Comment: Where does the $2$ come from, when you estimate the sum of squares of sides? Should it not be $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I am squaring the distances. I have assumed that all the pairwise distances are increased by a factor less than $\sqrt{2}$ and have shown that this contradicts the short diagonal lemma. My point is that the the pair of points can be any , not just the diagonals, as described in the link.